# Creating model event not firing in observer

Tags: php, laravel, events, eloquent, observers

I have the following files:

**ModelObserverProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Profile;
use App\Observers\UserObserver;
use App\Observers\ProfileObserver;

class ModelObserverProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        User::observe(UserObserver::class);
        Profile::observe(ProfileObserver::class);
    }

    public function register()
    {}
}
```

**UserObserver.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\User;

class UserObserver
{
    public function creating(User $user)
    {
        dd('Creating...');
        // Hash the users password when creating.
        $user->password = bcrypt($user->password);

        // Create a new profile for the user.
        $user->profiles()->create(['name' => 'guest-' . time()]);
    }
}
```

I have loaded the ModelObserverProvider in my config/app.php, however, notice the `dd('Creating...');` ? When creating a new user via `User::create($request->all())` this does not appear to be firing at all? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Profile;
use App\Observers\UserObserver;
use App\Observers\ProfileObserver;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  /**
    * Bootstrap any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {
       User::observe(UserObserver::class);
       Profile::observe(ProfileObserver::class);
    }

    /**
      * Register any application services.
      *
      * @return void
      */
      public function register()
      {}
}
```

Comment: So as it turns out it was down to a custom name spacing, replacing everything back to the default App namespace solved the issue, my Observer is now firing.

Comment: @SeriousJelly if this really solved the problem, it looks like your service provider wasn't registered, as I said before. You could run `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan config:clear` and  `composer dumpauto` commands to solve it.

Comment: Every time one creates a service provider should register it on `config/app.php` just saying.

Comment: @Chay22 OP added it to the config, but it seems Laravel didn't load it because of cached data.

Comment: The service provider was loading, I dd()'ed inside the service provider and it was loading, it was due to the namespacing, changing back to the default App namespace for everything solved it, my service provider and observers now work